# How to authorize lambda to perform ses:SendEmail with CDK?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-ses, aws-cdk

I'm getting runtime exception:

> AccessDenied: User
> arn:aws:sts::431535252:assumed-role/...some-lambda' is not authorized
> to perform 'ses:SendEmail' on resource
> `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:52452465462:identity/contact@somedomain.com

Looking at the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ses-readme.html), I wasn't able to figure out how to grant that permission.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Currently, need to manually add a policy to the execution role for the lambda:

```
theLambda.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['ses:SendEmail', 'SES:SendRawEmail'],
  resources: ['*'],
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
}));
```